# How do you generate an x509Certificate based solely on a public key in RSA format?

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle, x509, pem

I have an RSA public key in an XML format. I need to take this key and create an x.509 Certificate using that public key. I do not have access to the private key to complete the key pair. All examples that I have found involve either generating the key pair or having access to both the public and private keys.

Below is a small snippet from a test routine I have been working on to accomplish this.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        provider.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>puEVvRbrLAz.......c1W5j/vqJSUrXo16k=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>");

       Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters key = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetRsaPublicKey(provider);

//<!*** Do some code to take RsaKeyParameters and create an x.509 Certificate ***>

        var fOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\certificate.pem", false);
        var pw = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemWriter(fOut);
        pw.WriteObject(key);
```

Comment: Such certificate would give you nothing (not saying that you would have to sign it somehow). Why would you need to do that?

Comment: You can't create a valid X.509 certificate with only a public key.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the issue of impossibility of generating a certificate using a public key only.

AFAIK, **certificate must be signed**. And it must be done with a private key - that's why you need one for generating a certificate. If certificate is signed with the paired private key of the open key you are going to issue a certificate for, than it is a self-signed certificate. Otherwise you need a private key of so called *Certificate Authority* for signing.